# Meaning of `A(A == -Inf) = -realmax;`

Tags: matlab, octave

I was looking at Octave implementation of `expm` and fell over this line:

```
A(A == -Inf) = -realmax;
```

where `A` is a matrix.

What is the effect of the command?

Comment: Is the effect simply to replace `-Inf` entries in `A` with `-realmax`?

Comment: Yes, that's it, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: It has the same effect as `A = max(A, -realmax)`. I prefer this form. I presume, but am not sure, it will be more efficient.

Comment: It is not shorthand. It's just [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)

Comment: Thanks for the link @LuisMendo . Clear explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It puts the value `-realmax` in every entry of `A` which is `-Inf`.

For instance, let's say

```matlab
A = [1 -Inf 3; Inf -Inf 4; 0 0 0];
```

Then the command above would change `A` to the following:

```matlab
[1 -realmax 3; Inf -realmax 4; 0 0 0]
```

Comment: `realmax` is a function: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/realmax.html

Comment: @LuisMendo, you convinced me.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis \o/